# Arduino UNO WiFi RestServer returning "not found"

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, web-server

I'm trying to run RestServer on my Arduino UNO WiFi, and I'm currently using the tutorial from Arduino: http://www.arduino.org/learning/tutorials/boards-tutorials/restserver-and-restclient

Everything works as expected, but whenever I change this:

```
  // is "digital" command?
  if (command == "digital") {
    digitalCommand(client);
  }
```

To this:

```
  // is "digital" command?
  if (command == "test") {
    digitalCommand(client);
  }
```

and go the the same URL but instead of "digital", user "test", I get a "not found" error.

(from http://*url*/arduino/digital/13/1 to http://*url*/arduino/test/13/1)

Am I doing something wrong? Or are the URLs in that example the only possible ones?

Comment: Try "/arduino/digital/test"...